# WAMP update to php 5.5.12 has stopped all my sql prepare statements from working

Tags: php, sql, localhost, wamp, prepared-statement

I recently updated my wamp version so that it now included php 5.5.12 as i wanted to use one of the new features, now unfortunately i did this half way through a project and have just noticed its rendered most of my current project useless.

It seems like the prepare statements have stopped working, but knowing my luck it runs deeper than that. I havent changed any of the code on my pages so im pretty sure its the update that has caused this.

so at the top of my page i have the following

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testsite');
```

and i then have a form which runs a couple of queries to populate the form elements which is like this:

```
    <div id="filter_container" class="fluid">

        <h3 class="fluid filter_header">
            Filter Search Results
        </h3>

        <input type="search" placeholder="Keyword..." style="width:44.95%; padding:1.5%;">

        <select  style="width:25%; padding:1.5%">
            <option value="0">Postcode / Town</option>
            <?php
            $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
            $stmt->prepare("SELECT townID,town FROM tbl_towns WHERE townID != ? ORDER BY town ASC");
            $fake = 0;
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$fake);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($townID,$town);
            while($stmt->fetch())
            {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $townID?>"><?php echo $town?></option><?php
            }
            $stmt->close()?>
        </select>

        <select style="width:25%; padding:1.5%;">
            <option value="0">Category</option>
            <?php
            $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
            $stmt->prepare("SELECT categoryID,category FROM tbl_category WHERE categoryID != ? ORDER BY category ASC");
            $fake = 0;
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$fake);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($catID,$cat);
            while($stmt->fetch())
            {?>
               <option value="<?php echo $catID?>"><?php echo $cat?></option><?php
            }
            $stmt->close()?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

but noting is being populated where as it was before the update?

there are other varibles which are now 'undefined' after the update and causing errors, but one thing at a time :)

would appreciate any help to solve this

## EDIT

OK found the problem :( during the update my database files were obv wiped, but i backed up the wap files and just copied the mysql files into the new folder, but it seem like something has gone wrong and the tables have not been re-created :( thus not existing and hence the major issues im having! does anyone know what other files i need to copy inorder to retrieve my database?

Many Thanks

Comment: Stop assuming things will always work. mysqli defaults to mysql-type operation and will return boolean false on failure. check for that failure: `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...); if ($stmt === false) { die(mysqli_error($db));`

Comment: thank you for your recomendation, will keep that in mind in the future! it didnt throw up any new error so guess thats a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

OK found the problem :( during the update my database files were obv wiped, but i backed up the wamp files and just copied all the mysql files i though were needed into the new folder

but when i checked my php myadmin i noticed all my tables had been deleted :O obviously i hadnt copied all the correct database files over from the old installation

finally found out which file i missed and now that it has been copied over everything is now working again  :D

Panic Over, Lesson learnt!!

thanks for all your comments and suggestions have taken them all on board!

Answer (score -1):

You should probably try this

```
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
```

Hope it helps:)
 Anyway, you should try use the PDO driver. It offers more flexibility :).
You could just set your preferred type of db and work with it.

Comment: exactly where in the OP's queries are there colours/calories/fruit? "My car isn't working". "Have you tried this banana bread?"

Comment: thanks for your input victor but i cant seem to figure this out :( can you elaborate please? thank you